# Am looking for a way to add new cloudwatch events to existing redshift cluster via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

So i already have an existing redshift cluster running which I created with cloudformation, Now I need to add a new cloudwatch event to this cluster like below code, How do i map the new alarm with existing cluster.

This is for existing AWS Redshift cluster

```
   Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
   Properties:
     AlarmDescription: !Join [ " ", [ "Health status alarm for", !Ref RedshiftCluster, "Redshift Cluster"]]
     AlarmActions:
     - !Ref redshiftClusterSNSTopic
     MetricName: HealthStatus
     Namespace: AWS/Redshift
     Statistic: Average
     Period: 300
     EvaluationPeriods: 3
     Threshold: 1
     ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
     Dimensions:
     - Name: ClusterIdentifier
       Value: !Ref CARedshiftCluster
```

Not sure how to do this, help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work? Are you adding it to the template and then doing an Update Stack?

Comment: No, that is the question now someone has created the Redshift cluster manually and now i need to run a CF template which updates the cluster with cloudwatch alarm. I have written something as above and trying to find a way to integrate this with existing cluster. Like plugging in the alerms and in future for any new alerts will just run this template which will add the alarms.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do it via CloudFormation? The `ClusterIdentifier` would want to refer to the part of the CloudFormation template where Redshift was launched, but you're saying that Redshift was launched manually, so that won't work. You could instead substitute the Cluster ID that you see in the console. However, it would be easier to simply do all this in the console rather than in CloudFormation. Thus, any reason you want to use CloudFormation to do it?

Comment: Ok I got your point John, There is no particular reason but will use the cluster ID and try to run it.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) a try. It is an online cloudformation template generator. It is regularly updated. As of now it does support cloudwatch.